# separate a foreach loop's results by letter

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query:

```
try
{
  $sql = 'SELECT park_id, name, town, state, country
          FROM tpf_parks wHERE  ORDER BY name ASC';
  $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Error fetching parks: ' . $e->getMessage();
  //include 'error.html.php';//
  exit();
}

$output = 'Parks Loaded';
//include 'output.html.php';//

foreach ($result as $row)
{
  $parklist[] = array(
    'park_id' => $row['park_id'],
    'name' => $row['name'],
    'town' => $row['town'],
    'state' => $row['state'],
    'country' => $row['country']
  );
}
include 'parks.html.php';
```

and this is parks.html.php

```
<?php foreach ($parklist as $park):?>
    <a href="park.php?park_id=<?php echo $park['park_id'];?>">
        <h2><?php echo $park['name'];?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo $park['town'],',',$park['state'],',',$park['country'];?></h3>
    </a>
    <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm looking for some way that the foreach loop can be altered so I can split the results into groups sorted by the first letter. This is so I can put a html anchor for each Letter making it easier for the user to locate a particular record by clicking a link at the top of the page (A B C D E etc) . I am clueless as to how to achieve this.

Comment: check the SQL statement, you have a  `WHERE` clause but no conditions. I don't think it's part of your problem here, but anyway...

Comment: oops! I think that was where I was messing about with different queries. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not gonna be the prettiest solution unless you use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), which would allow you to create the arrays and assign them based on a loop with an array of letters of the alphabet.

But if that's too complex for you, just do something like this:

```
$a = array();
$b = array();
$c = array();
...

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $letter = strtolower(substr($row['name'], 0, 1));
    if ($letter == 'a') $a.push($row);
    else if($letter == 'b') $b.push($row);
    ...
}
```

Obviously, repeating for every letter.

Then, when you loop through the arrays for the html creation, you'll have to do a foreach() through each letter array.

Comment: `$a.push` is not a thing in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
   //add to sub-array with first letter of $row['name']
   $parklist[strtolower($row['name'][0]][] = array(
   ....


//rather then give the whole alphabet with possible empties, check for existing letters:
$letters = array_keys($parklist)
```

Or, for safety in multibyte environments (utf-8 for instance):

```
   $parklist[mb_strtolower(mb_substr($row['name'],0,1))][]= array(
```

(assuming you have a correct `mb_internal_encoding()`)

If you want diacretics to resolve to their base (`ö` to `o` for instance);

```
    $parklist[iconv('whateveryourinputcharsetis','ASCII//TRANSLIT',mb_strtolower(mb_substr($row['name'],0,1)))][]= array(
```

Note that you *sort* in `MySQL` by the name column so your entries should be in order, provided you have the correct `COLLATION`:

The right character set / collation:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t ( f char(1)) charset=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)
mysql> show full columns from t;
+-------+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field | Type    | Collation       | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| f     | char(1) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------
mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a'),('p'),('ä'),('o'),('ñ'),('ò');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY f;
+------+
| f    |
+------+
| a    |
| ä    |
| ñ    |
| o    |
| ò    |
| p    |
+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But the wrong wreaks havoc:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY CONVERT(f USING ascii);
+------+
| f    |
+------+
| ä    |
| ñ    |
| ò    |
| a    |
| o    |
| p    |
+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm such a beginner I don't fully understand what I need to do. So far I have changed the result to this `foreach ($result as $row)
{
$parklist[mb_strtolower(mb_substr($row['name'],0,1))][]= array(
'park_id' => $row['park_id'],
'name' => $row['name'],
'town' => $row['town'],
'state' => $row['state'],
'country' => $row['country']

);
}`

Comment: My db uses utf-8 do I also need to change the foreach ($parklist as $park) loop? making the change above only lists the comma's that usually separate the name, state, and country records

Comment: It would work fine, but keep in mind you have nested the arrays, so you also need to nest `foreach`s: `foreach ($parklist as $letter => $parkswiththisletter){ echo 'Letter: '.$letter;foreach($parkswiththisletter as $park){ echo $park['name'];/*etc*/}}`

Comment: BTW: if you are not changing the keys, you don't need to assign them in a new array: `$parklist[mb_strtolower(mb_substr($row['name'],0,1))][]=$row;` seems fine to me.